# Create just smallest possible rootfs using yocto

Tags: yocto, rootfs, initramfs

I want to create am minimal Linux system. I have compiled the kernel myself, but I want to use Yocto to build my rootfs. How can I build the smallest possible rootfs to startup and system and open a shell without building the kernel? Also, how can I choose the type of rootfs? I'd like it to be initramfs so I can then embed it in my kernel image.

Comment: You're probably using the wrong build tool.  A *"minimal Linux system"* and/or the *"the smallest possible rootfs"* is trivial to accomplish with Buildroot.

Answer (score 3):

Without more details both questions would require very long answers. Luckily the  Development Manual covers the issues: See [Building a tiny system](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev-manual/building.html#building-a-tiny-system) and [Building an initramfs image](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev-manual/building.html#building-an-initial-ram-filesystem-initramfs-image). I would suggest starting with those and asking more specific questions if needed.

Comment: thank you for your response. Regarding the "building an initramfs image" section in the manual, my problem is with the last point "Build the Kernel Image and the initramfs Image". I'd like to build just the initramfs without downloading/building the kernel or other unecessary things like qemu.

Comment: @josecm Why would you prefer not to build the kernel?

Comment: I am just used to configure and build the kernel myself.